# can I copy an array to a hash table?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, hashtable

I have an array which its elements are float .how can I copy this array to a hash table?

thanks

Comment: A hash table only makes sense when you have two values to relate.

Comment: What's the hash table going to be used for?  What's the key/value pair?

Comment: A hashtable maps keys to values - you have an array of floats. Do you know how you want to generate your keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily put them into a `Hashtable` of `int` -> `float`.  The following method will use their index in the array as the key.

```
float[] arr;
Hashtable<Integer, Float> table = new Hashtable<Integer, Float>(arr.length);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    table.put(i, arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why someone may need to do that?

Comment: @khachik, maybe they will be adding new values with different int values as keys...(i dunno)

Comment: I think that when I want to find a duplicate value in an array it will have O(nlogn) but with coping array to hash table , I can get my duplicate number in O(n) .is it correct?

Comment: @user, then you want a `Set`.  See @Bozho's answer.

Comment: @khachik: A `Map<Integer,?>` is a very common implementation of a sparse array. This would meet solve the problem of converting an existing array to a sparse array.

Comment: @Mark So just make a sparse array initially. I think the OP is learning something, and it would be good to know what to help to find the right direction. Ok, whatever

Comment: i could also see the "reverse" of this, where you'd put the floats as the key, to do a reverse lookup of what float was in what index...but yeah  "why" has been the best question so far.

Comment: @Khachik: I wasn't trying to guess at what the OP needs.  You asked why *someone* may need to do that.  Clearly it's not needed for the OP's situation.

Comment: @user: you should include those clarifications in your question.  The set route doesn't really help you detect which values are duplicates; it only tells you whether there are duplicates or not (by comparing the size afterwards).  A Map *is* a good solution for finding which are duplicates, mapping Float->Integer.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

An array cannot directly correspond to a Map. It can correspond to a set.

```
new HashSet(Arrays.asList(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashtable implements Map, so you would need to pair every float with some key.

Comment: This seems better served as a comment when compared to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given the OP's clarification of his/her requirements in jjnguy's answer, here's an `O(n)` (amortized) way to count occurrences of unique values in a float array:

```
float[] values;
Map<Float, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<Float, Integer>();
for ( float f : values ) {
    int count = occurrences.containsKey(f) ? occurrences.get(f) : 0;
    occurrences.put(f, count+1);
}

//then find multiple occurrences by finding entries with a value > 0
for ( Entry<Float, Integer> entry : occurrences.values() ) {
    if ( entry.getValue() > 1 ) {
       System.out.println("Duplicate: " + entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

In practice it's usually smelly to use a float as a key to anything, or to use a float in a way that pretends it's a discrete value.  Floating point types are typically used to simulate "continuous" values, where for all intents and purposes 7.000000000012 should be considered the same as 7.000000000013.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many there are of different float values in your array, the best solution would be a multiset (which is typically built on top of a `Map<T, Integer>`). With [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), you could do this:

```
float[] floats = ...
Multiset<Float> multiset = HashMultiset.create(Floats.asList(floats));
for (Multiset.Entry<Float> entry : multiset.entrySet()) {
  Float value = entry.getElement();
  int count = entry.getCount();
  ...
}
```